# How to view all the downloaded podcast episodes on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, podcasts, podcasts.app

I've noticed on an iPhone I am unable to view all (and only) downloaded podcast episodes. I can connect the phone to a Mac and via iTunes I can see all the downloaded episodes but I am unable to delete any of them...

So my question is how to view all (and only) downloaded podcast episodes on the iPhone?

Comment: I'm not sure, but to make it simpler for me, the way I do it is turn off automatic downloads, have it set so it automatically deletes downloaded podcasts, and then if there's anything I want to keep, I download it and save it, and then it shows up in the Saved tab of a podcast. If you do that, there's your answer.

Comment: How to access the "saved tab" on an iphone?

Comment: Podcasts > My Podcasts > choose a podcast > above the list of podcasts, you can choose I played, feed, or Saved. If you downloaded *and* saved a podcast, it'll be in that Saved area.

Comment: No, I only saw unplayed and feed. There is no saved tab while I have podcast episodes downloaded and saved. All my other settings are identical to yours.

Comment: Just to check, could you provide me with your current iPhone model and iOS software version? I also don't see a Saved tab unless I have at least one saved podcast episode. In iOS 9, you need to hit the three dots to the right of a podcast episode and press Save Episode. You'll also want to press Download Episode if the option is available. Then it will download and will show up under Saved.

Comment: Oh I see. I only tapped the cloud to download the episodes. The problem is I want to delete some of them but now I can't since I can't dig through the list to see all the episodes downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since this question has been asked. As of now, you can do it like this:

1. Click on "Library" in the Podcasts app.
2. Click "Edit" in the upper right hand corner.
3. Tap the circle next to "Downloaded Episodes" to check it.
4. Click "Done". You can now see the "Downloaded Episodes" option below "Library" text (under "Shows" and "Episodes").

This section contains **only** downloaded Podcasts.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `Settings->General->Storage & iCloud Usage->Manage Storage->Podcast`
there will show all the podcasts you have downloaded.

Comment: That will show podcasts, not podcast *episodes*, which is what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to the podcast in iTunes application. Set the configuration of the podcast to limit episodes off and download episodes on. Set all episodes to unread and iTunes should download all of them.

Search your computer for the folder with the MP3 files if needed, usually they are found in this location:

```
C:\Users\%username%\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media\Podcasts\%podcastname%
```